# Consulta DATETIME por horas

Tags: sql

Necesito hacer una búsqueda por horas, es decir que me aparezca un campo en concreto filtrado por X hora

[image: SQL server]

Comment: ¿En qué motor de base de datos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tambien puedes usar la funcion:

```
DATEPART(PARTE, PARAMETRO)
```

PARTE pueden ser las siguientes constantes DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND, YEAR, las partes que componen un datetime

PARAMETRO es el dato del que quieres obtener una parte.

La funcion DATEPART te permite obtener una parte del TIME o DATE o DATETIME que necesites evaluar.

si por ejemplo quieres obtener todo los registros entre las 8 y las 9 puedes hacer algo asi:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabla 
WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, fechahora) BETWEEN 8 and 9;
```

Answer (score 2):

En Bases de Datos de Oracle puedes usar:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM SYSDATE) FROM MiTabla;
```

Sacado de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846530/retrieve-only-hour-from-timestamp-field-stored-in-db

Answer (score 2):

Esto puede ayudarte:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708027/mysql-select-hour-in-datetime-and-group

```
SELECT HOUR(ShoppingDate), COUNT(*) FROM YourTable
GROUP BY HOUR(ShoppingDate)
```

Publicado originalmente por @JonSkeet

Answer (score 0):

Esto te puede ayudar:

```
SELECT * FROM Tabla
WHERE FechaUltimaModificacion BETWEEN '20161010 10:00:00' AND '20161010 20:00:00'
```

Poniendo los parámetros de horas en el `VARCHAR` de la fecha a buscar SQL los interpreta a la perfección.

Answer (score 0):

Proba con esto, para que te devuelva en el formato yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss(24h)
    SELECT convert(varchar(25), getdate(), 120)

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor es usar la función

```
to_char(nombre_campo_fecha, 'HH24')
```

esto lo pones en la consulta de tu tabla y te tiene que devolver la hora únicamente.